# Async task not working in real device

Tags: android, intel-galileo

I have project get json value form a web which hosted by intel galileo. When i using async task in android emulator it work perfect but when i try the same code  in real device it throws NullPointerException.  Anyone can explain for me why and how can i solve this problem. Thanks!

```
package com.example.administrator.dbin.ClassLibrary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.administrator.dbin.Activity.MainActivity;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.Activity.ShowDataActivity;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.Adapter.DataAdapter;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.Adapter.RouteAdapter;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.Model.Data;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.Model.JsonDBin;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.Model.Route;
import com.example.administrator.dbin.R;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class AsyncData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JsonDBin>{

    private Activity context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private  View view;
    //private String httpURL = "http://192.168.78.1:8080/sendData";
    private String httpURL = "http://192.168.0.100:8080/sendData";
    private int codeProcess;

    String first_floor;
    String end_floor;
    String max_weight;

    public AsyncData(Activity context_, int codeProcess_, View view_) {
        this.context = context_;
        this.codeProcess = codeProcess_;
        this.view = view_;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.myPreferences,  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        first_floor = String.valueOf( sharedPreferences.getInt("floor_first", 1));
        end_floor = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("floor_end", 1));
        max_weight = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("floor_end", 1));

        httpURL += "/" + first_floor + "/" + end_floor + "/" + max_weight;

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.str_progress_title);
        dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.str_progress_message));
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonDBin doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(httpURL);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8"));
            JsonDBin jsonDBin = new Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, JsonDBin.class);

            return jsonDBin;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JsonDBin jsonDBin) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonDBin);

        int floor_flag;

        if (codeProcess == ShowDataActivity.CODE_DATA){

            List<Data> tmp = jsonDBin.getData();
            List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

            floor_flag = tmp.get(0).getId();
            data.add(new Data(floor_flag," ",-100));

            for (Data item : tmp){

                if (floor_flag != item.getId()){
                    floor_flag = item.getId();
                    data.add(new Data(floor_flag, "", -100));
                }
                data.add(item);
            }

            ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
            DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(context,R.layout.listview_content_row, data);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else if (codeProcess == ShowDataActivity.CODE_ROUTE ){
            List<Route> tmp = jsonDBin.getRoute();
            if (!(tmp.isEmpty())){
                List<Route> route = new ArrayList<Route>();

                floor_flag = tmp.get(0).getId();
                route.add(new Route(floor_flag, " ", -100));

                for (Route item : tmp){

                    if (floor_flag != item.getId()){
                        floor_flag = item.getId();
                        route.add(new Route(floor_flag, "", -100));
                    }
                    route.add(item);
                }

                ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewRoute);
                RouteAdapter adapter = new RouteAdapter(context, R.layout.listview_content_row, route);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is my logcat

com.example.administrator.dbin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.administrator.dbin.ClassLibrary.AsyncData.onPostExecute(AsyncData.java:94)
            at com.example.administrator.dbin.ClassLibrary.AsyncData.onPostExecute(AsyncData.java:30)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Without your code we can only guess.

Comment: Run your code in real device through data cable and when error occurs then paste error from logcat here for understand your problem..

Comment: thanks please see my logcat

Comment: Your exception is in onPostExecute, why aren't you posting the code? Do people suppose to guess?

Comment: that my code, when i debug it catch error in block try catch, and i don't know why

Comment: I think jsonDBin is NULL. You should debug doInBackground as it's probably returning NULL.

Comment: but when i run emulator it work well, why in real device it return NULL?

Comment: Probably some connectivity issue, but it's hard to say without seeing the exception. Debug and see the exception in doInBackground (It's in try catch clause now, so you don't see it).

Comment: so do you know how to connect android device with a website which hosted by intel galileo?

Comment: You should really start debugging your app and see what exceptions you get, instead of letting people guess. Good luck with your problem here.

Comment: Could your real device connect with the web?